# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \right]$ converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \right]$ converge absolutely?

***What I attempted:-***

If $a_n=(-1)^n \left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \right]$, then by *Leibnitz* test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$ .

Now, $|a_n|=\left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \right]$. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}&=\frac{e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} For large $n$, this ratio takes the form of $\frac{0}{0}$. Moreover, it is not difficult to see that $\left(|a_n|\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ form a diminishing sequence. Hence, intuition may lead to answer that it converges absolutely, which, I think is not true. I am not getting any way to proceed.
A hint will be highly appreciated. How could we suspect it to be divergent or convergent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's well-known that the sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ increases with limit $e$. So, you question is "Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converge where
$b_n=e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$?".

Now
$$\ln\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=n\left(
\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+O(n^{-3})\right)
=1-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2}).$$
Exponentiating,
$$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right)
=e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right).$$
Then
$$b_n=\frac{e}{2n}+O(n^{-2}).$$
Therefore $\sum b_n$ diverges, although $\sum (-1)^nb_n$ converges.